# lit: how to apply style to nested template?

Tags: html, web-component, lit-element, lit-html, lit

There is a lit element `container-element` which has has nested lit elements `gmail-item`.

How do you apply styles to nested elements so that the last `gmail-item` has `border-none`?

Currently, the styling `li:last-of-type` doesn't propegate to nested lit elements which contain `li`.

```js
      @container-element
  
      li:last-of-type {
        border-bottom: none;
      }

      <gmail-item></gmail-item>
      <gmail-item></gmail-item>
      <gmail-item></gmail-item>
      <gmail-item></gmail-item>
      <gmail-item></gmail-item>
```

```js
@gmail-item

li {
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}


<li>I am gmail item</li>
```

edit:

tried the following.

```js
      <style>
        gmail-item::slotted(li) {
          border: 1px solid orange;
        }
        gmail-item li {
          border: 1px solid orange;
        }
        li {
          border: 1px solid orange;
        }
      </style>
      <gmail-item></gmail-item>
           ........
```

But unfortunately none of them apply styles to the `li` inside `gmail-item`.

I also tried adding `createRendeRoot` but this removed all styling inside `gmail-item`.

```js
@gmail-item

createRenderRoot() {
return this;
}
```

Also tried setting `li border-bottom to inherit`.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70491286/css-not-working-properly-on-custom-html-elements

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I have tried the solutions provided but unfortunately no styling has been applied to the `li` element.

Comment: CSS is encapsulated in web components, which means your inner element don't "see" any outside CSS, and the CSS you have in the shadow DOM won't affect anything outside of your component. *Nothing bleeds out, nothing trickles in* (except inherited properties, e.g. custom properties aka "CSS variables").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be css variables. It is a standard and it is scoped.

```css
.container-1 {
  --my-status: grey;
}

.container-2 > gmail-item:first-child {
  --my-status: orange;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import {
  LitElement,
  html,
  css
} from "https://unpkg.com/lit-element/lit-element.js?module";

class MyContainer extends LitElement {
  static get styles() {
    return css`
      .wrapper {
        min-height: 100px;
        min-width: 50%;
        margin: 5em;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: lightblue;
      }
    `;
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <div class="wrapper">
        <slot></slot>
      </div>
    `;
  }
}

class GmailItem extends LitElement {
  static get styles() {
    return css`
      .status {
        margin: 1em;
        border: 2px solid white;
        background-color: var(--my-status, red);
      }
    `;
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <div class="status">STATUS</div>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define("my-container", MyContainer);
customElements.define("gmail-item", GmailItem);
</script>

<my-container class="container-1">
  <gmail-item></gmail-item>
  <gmail-item></gmail-item>
</my-container>

<my-container class="container-2">
    <gmail-item></gmail-item>
    <gmail-item style="--my-status: magenta"></gmail-item>
</my-container>
```